# PHP ODBC "AND" statement error

Tags: php, sql, odbc

I get a SQL error on this line:

(using ODBC Connection with php)

```
$sql = "SELECT WO_NUM, PM_MECHANICAL, PM_APPLICATIONS, LINE_ITEM FROM Schedule WHERE PM_MECHANICAL IS NOT NULL AND WO_NUM <>";
```

The statement is supposed to query the items where PM_MECHANICAL has something in the field, and where WO_NUM is an integer (no letters or characters in the field).

Answer (score 1):

This is your SQL:

```
SELECT WO_NUM, PM_MECHANICAL, PM_APPLICATIONS, LINE_ITEM
FROM Schedule
WHERE PM_MECHANICAL IS NOT NULL AND WO_NUM <>
```

So, `WO_NUM` is not equal to *what* exactly?  You need something.  For instance:

```
SELECT WO_NUM, PM_MECHANICAL, PM_APPLICATIONS, LINE_ITEM
FROM Schedule
WHERE PM_MECHANICAL IS NOT NULL AND WO_NUM <> 0
```

EDIT:

Specifying that `WO_NUM` is an integer value for a character string depends on the database.  In SQL Server, the following would be good enough:

```
WHERE isnumeric(WO_NUM) = 1 and WO_NUM not like '%.%'
```

In MySQL, you can use regular expressions, or the easy conversion from strings to numbers:

```
where WO_NUM not regexp '[^0-9]'
```

Comment: Maybe I was using the wrong thing. How do I specify if WO_NUM is an integer?